# looking for advice on how to use different dates in the Where section of an sql viewdepending on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have been trying to get the following to work for a while and I keep encountering road-blocks so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I need to create a view.  The logic is as follows:

```
Select (database fields) 
from table01
where 
     (if current month < 7 then use 01/07/{previous year}
else
     use 01/07/{current year})
```

I can't use an If (CASE) in the Where section of a query so I am not sure how to proceed.  I also can't use variables in View statements so I am a bit stuck there.

I looked at creating a SPROC to return the correct date value but I don't think I can use a SPROC in a view as part of the Where statement can I?

Has anyone got any suggestions about how I might tackle this problem?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `OR` and `AND` in your `WHERE` clause:

Try something like this and adjust it due to your needs:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ((DATEPART(Month, MyDate) < 7 AND CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DATEPART(YEAR, 
MyDate)-1)+'0701' AS date) > MyDate)
OR (DATEPART(Month, MyDate) >= 7 AND CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DATEPART(YEAR, 
MyDate))+'0701' AS date) > MyDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out.

I created a CTE Query to return the correct date

Comment: You should either delete the question or provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is how I came up with the solution:

I used the following code when creating the view.  The CTE Query returns the correct date depending upon the current month and the main part of the query then uses that date in the Where statement

`*Create view [dbo].[viewName] as
with get_date(useDate) as
    (SELECT case when month(getdate()) < 7 then
            (convert(varchar(10),(year(getdate())-1)) + '-07-01 00:00:00.000') 
    else
            (convert(varchar(10),(year(getdate()))) + '-07-01 00:00:00.000') 
    End)

select a.amount, a.charge_date
from databasetable a, get_date  where (a.CHARGE_DATE < get_date.useDate)*`